# hooking via hotpatching... non exported class method in dll

Tags: reverse-engineering

I have been studying this method of API hooking using the mechanisms for hotpatching in windows dlls.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/0xF9EB_Hooking.aspx

I was wondering if anyone would know of a way to extend that to hooking non exported functions such as a C++ constructor for an internal class inside of a DLL.  I have already know the address via dis-assembly... the problem I am having is how to set up the right calling conventions so that I can call the original function inside of my hook function.

I'm already to the point to where my hook function gets called... the program crashes because I can't return the results of calling the original function.

Lets assume we are talking about hooking an internal class constructor with a prototype something like this:

```
public __thiscall <class_name>::<class_name>(<single pointer arg to another object>)
```

Answer (score 3):

depending on how your module is loaded, you can generally just overwrite the relative or absolute addresses at their respective call sites, else you need to make a trampolining function, for which its easier to use something like MS Detours.

In terms of the correct prototype for `__thiscall` based class member functions, you need some trickery, as you can't generally use `__thiscall` outside classes. The fastest and easiest way is to use `__fastcall` and ignore the second parameter. So your first definition becomes `void __fastcall myctor(myobj* pObj)`.

Comment: Whatever you do, avoid Detours. The free version (not the $10k one) can cause a variety of fun and creative segfaults and other crashes (it also tends not to function on 64-bit systems, even within 32-bit processes). EasyHook, while greatly lacking documentation, is a much more stable alternative (and somewhat safer in spots).

Comment: @peachykeen: thats why I said *something like*, as I'm not a fan of detours either, it just happens to be well know...

Answer (score -1):

Define it as a typical `__stdcall` function except that you'll have `this` pointer in `ecx` register. If you need this pointer, then use the `__asm` keyword to get the value:

```
void __stdcall HookedConstructor( SomeObject *pObject){
    HookedClass *pClass;
    __asm mov pClass, ecx;
    ...
}
```

Note that you'll have to do this at the beginning of the call. Otherwise, the value of `ecx` register may be overwritten.

Comment: most class function definitions use `__thiscall` unless they are specifically told not to, so using `__cdecl` arbitrarily is gonna lead to nice bouts of stack corruption.

Comment: It's much safer and cleaner to provide a hook/stub class, perhaps with members if you have information on those, and implement the functions within that then use pointer-to-member in the hooks.